# When I disassemble a .so file, How IDA pro can get parameter & return information of "memset"?

Tags: android, c, reverse-engineering, ida

When I disassemble a .so file, How IDA Pro can show the information of a libc function (such as: memset) like this:

```
.plt:000184D8 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000184D8
.plt:000184D8 ; Attributes: thunk
.plt:000184D8
.plt:000184D8 ; void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
.plt:000184D8 memset                                  ; CODE XREF: sub_18F10+2Cp
.plt:000184D8                                         ; getImgName+34p ...
.plt:000184D8                 ADRL    R12, 0xEB4E0
.plt:000184E0                 LDR     PC, [R12,#(memset_ptr - 0xEB4E0)]! ; __imp_memset
.plt:000184E0 ; End of function memset
.plt:000184E0
.plt:000184E4 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How IDA pro can get parameter & return information of "memset"? 
It still show function information though I remove file: \IDA PRO\sig\libc.sig.
Thanks!